# Analytics: Web Property ID not used for _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', …])

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

See screenshot below. In Google Tag Manager, the Web Property ID is set.
However, when executing `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', …])`, then according to
[Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en), it is not available:

```
Account ID: UA-XXXXX-X
```

Only when setting the Web Property ID via JavaScript, then `_trackEvent` works:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'registration',  'social', user.id.toString()]);
```

*Is it really necessary to set the Web Property ID again in JavaScript? How do I find out more?*

[image: Edited screen shot of Google Tag Manager]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding events manually and trying to get to work with GTM (Google tag manager). You  can actually track events automatically with GTM. Below is a link to that:
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/10/03/google-tag-manager-auto-event-tracking/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1391111362

Other than that, instead of adding the Google Id through the default Google Analytics Tag that is created for you. Just create a custom javascript tag and paste your google analytics code in their and make sure it fires on all pages. That should do it as well!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of tracking events automatically with GTM. However, that doesn't seem to be possible in our case. Events should not be generated directly following a click: 1. User clicks on login button. 2. System tries to log the user in. 3. *Only after login was successful,* then an event should be generated, with a user ID returned by the login process.

Comment: For that instance you would create a virtual pageview which I think can also be created automatically. That pageview fires only on the confirm page. OR if the confirm URL is unique, then all you need is a goal.

Comment: There is no confirm page. Therefore the virtual page view would need to be generated by JavaScript. For that, also the Web Property ID needs to be set, and the code would look very similar to what I have in my question. At least that's how I understand things.